# OpenMP not work with an array access indirect

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I'm trying to optimize a loop in a parallel way with OpenMP.

```
  DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(INOUT) :: X(13541)
  INTEGER         , INTENT(IN)    :: NELEM,NELMAX !NELMAX = 25996 
  INTEGER         , INTENT(IN)    :: IKLE(NELMAX)
  DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(IN)    :: W(NELMAX)
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(IELEM) REDUCTION(+:X)
  DO IELEM = 1 , NELEM
    X(IKLE(IELEM)) = X(IKLE(IELEM)) + W(IELEM)
  ENDDO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

For any I and J different, it's possible that IKLE(I)=IKLE(J)

Increasing the number of the threads, I found that it takes even longer to run the loop. I use OMP_GET_WTIME() to time the job.

```
1 T  0.21943306922912598     
2 T  0.30610203742980957     
3 T  0.43688893318176270     
4 T  0.53783702850341797     
5 T  0.61055016517639160     
6 T  0.96715998649597168     
7 T  0.89582014083862305     
8 T   1.3073339462280273
```

I think the problem is caused by the array access indirect but I don't know how to deal with it in OpenMP

Comment: How large is `NELEM`?

Comment: NELEM has about 26000 elements

Comment: Have you tried varying the number of elements, specifically increasing it?

Comment: I increase it by times 100 to 2599600 elements but that doesn't help

Comment: How critical is that part of your code? I mean how many time do you call that subprogram in your code? is IKLE changing from one call to another?

Comment: @innoSPG in my demo it is called 5000 times without changing IKLE. But yeah, it need to be changed

Comment: Depending on how often it changes, I will suggest to sort it, that will speed the code. If somehow you were to go 5000 times without changing, the solution will definitely be to sort IKLE beforehand.

Comment: @innoSPG I agree, but I'd like to see if there's some way more direct. Anyway, I'll sort it and see how much time I can win back

Comment: @innoSPG sorry for asking again but I don't figure out how to sort it. If I sort IKLE I'll need to change W as well. Moreover, some elements in IKLE have the same value.

Comment: You are right! if you sort IKLE, you need to store the permutation and apply it to W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *it's possible that IKLE(I)=IKLE(J)* then you have a worse problem than irregular access trashing any hopes of efficient use of cached data, you have a *data race* -- there is no protection in your code against multiple threads writing to the same location 'simultaneously'.  Depending on the frequency of occurrence of `IKLE(I)=IKLE(J)` you may get lucky and never experience the race in practice. Or you may get unlucky.  Either way, as written, the program is a wrong 'un.

FWIW I agree with your suspicion that the irregular pattern of access to the elements of `X` is the root of the timing peculiarity you have reported, it requires a lot more movement of data through caches.

Also, while I'm writing, this line

```
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: NELEM,NELMAX = 25996
```

is wrong too, it's a syntax error to try to initialise a routine argument.

EDIT, in response to OP's comment:

*The dependence is surely another problem* -- not to my way of thinking, the dependence (by which I take it you mean what I call the data race) makes the program wrong, broken, erroneous.  The poor scaling is just an inconvenience.  The problem arises in the OpenMP version of the program because two, or more, threads may try to update the same element of `X` at about the same time.  The update is not atomic, the various operations that go on behind the scenes (read the data to a register, add the values in two registers together, write the data to a memory location, that sort of thing) may be interleaved in any way, and most of those interleavings will not leave the value in `X` as it would have been in a sequential execution of the program.

*Would you give some hints about the movement of data you said?* Not at this time, I've written enough.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The dependence is surely another problem (But I wonder can it be solved by the "reduction" clause since I got the correct result with it ). But I'm now confused with why openMP makes it even worse. Would you give some hints about the movement of data you said?